# Handle event emitter messages sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, eventemitter

```
myEmitter.on('data', handleData).
```

How can I have `handleData` invoked sequentially and not in parallel ?

For example: n `data` messages arrive grouped very closely in time together, and I want them to be handled in order **sequentially**, never in parallel.

Can I achieve this easily with some library ?

note: `handleData` is async

Comment: Is your "myEmitter" a DOM element or a self written library?

Comment: as an idea, you can use generator functions and invoke each `handleData` just after previous done

Answer (score 0):

If you have an additional event like `end` you'd be able to store each data item in an array in the order in which they arrive.
After you receive the `end` event you can process the previously stored data queue sequentially.

Example:

```
const dataQueue = [];
myEmitter.on('data', data => dataQueue.push(data));
myEmitter.on('end', () => dataQueue.forEach(handleData));
```

However, you won't be able to start processing before all data has arrived.

Answer (score 0):

I've built a library for doing this that you're welcome to try out.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-iterable

https://github.com/cbroad/event-iterable

It will allow you to use the for-await-of statement to sequentially process your events.

```js
const { EventIterable } = require( "event-iterable" );
async function example() {
    const it = EventIterable.wrap( myEmitter, "data" );
    /* You'll likely want to signal this loop to 
     * stop handling events by calling it.stop().
     * You could use a timer:
     *     setTimeout( () => it.stop(), 10000 );
     * or call it as a response to another event:
     *     myEmitter.once( "end", () => it.stop() );
     * or whenever you feel like it.
     */
    for await ( const handleData of it ) {
        // process your data here
    }
}
```